# How can I send BNB with metamask using web3.js (BSC Test Network)

Tags: web3js, cryptocurrency, metamask, binance-smart-chain

I want to send BNB from my metamask wallet using web3.js on BSC Test Network. I don't know how I can do it. This code sends ETH in my wallet, but I can't send BNB. I would be glad if you help..

```
      const holder = ethereum.selectedAddress;
    // paymentAddress is where funds will be send to
    const paymentAddress = '0xEdccc7De37305372c3a274aF32Bc0eed26D1891C'
    const amount = web3.utils.toWei("0.000011","ether")


    web3.eth.sendTransaction({
        from: holder,
        to: '0x0B75fbeB0BC7CC0e9F9880f78a245046eCBDBB0D',
        value: '1000000000000000000',
    }, function(err, transactionHash) {
      if (err) {
            console.log('Payment failed', err)
            $('#status').html('Payment failed')
        } else {
        console.log(transactionHash);
        $('#status').html('Payment successful')
       }
    });
```

Comment: Hi did you ever figure this one out?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `chainId: '56'` (which is the ID of BSC - [source](https://academy.binance.com/en/articles/connecting-metamask-to-binance-smart-chain)) in the transaction object.

Comment: I did it but it still tries to send ETH instead of BNB.